# Получить данные из массива php

Tags: php, массивы

подскажите пожалуйста, как получить данные `["disposition"]` из такого массива с помощью php?

````
array(1) {
  [1764431899]=>
  array(18) {
    ["companyID"]=>
    string(5) "27917"
    ["generalCallID"]=>
    string(10) "1764431899"
    ["callID"]=>
    string(10) "1764431899"
    ["startTime"]=>
    string(10) "1581412685"
    ["callType"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["internalNumber"]=>
    string(3) "901"
    ["internalAdditionalData"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["externalNumber"]=>
    string(10) ""
    ["srcNumber"]=>
    string(3) "901"
    ["customerData"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["employeeName"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["employeeEmail"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["dstNumbers"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["dstNumber"]=>
        string(10) ""
        ["waitsec"]=>
        int(0)
        ["billsec"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["disposition"]=>
        string(7) "CALLING"
        ["trunkNumber"]=>
        string(10) ""
      }
    }
    ["waitsec"]=>
    int(0)
    ["billsec"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["disposition"]=>
    string(7) "CALLING"
    ["isNewCall"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["trunkNumber"]=>
    string(10) ""
  }
}```
````

Comment: Всегда у массива такое строение (вложенность)?

Comment: @Arsen да, массив статичен.

Comment: Но ключи всегда меняются? как пример первый ключ `[1764431899]=>`

Comment: @Arsen да, ключ первый меняется, но он известен.

Comment: `$array = $arr2[1764431899]['disposition']` Так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если первый ключ массива всегда известен, можем обойти метод циклов и на прямую получить значение:

```
$key = '1764431899';

/* Первое значение в массиве*/
echo $array[$key]['disposition'];

/*Второе значение в массиве*/
echo $array[$key][0]['dstNumbers']['disposition'];
```